# getting line numbers in stack traces

Tags: android, codenameone, stack-trace

Codenameone clearly has the capability of providing line numbers
as well as function names in android stack traces.  It routinely
provides numbers for internal VM functions.   How can I get it to
add them for my own methods.

```
lib.ErrorX: createAllFixed #1 1024x499 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at lib.G.Error(Unknown Source)
at online.common.RepaintManager.createBlankImage(Unknown Source)
at online.common.RepaintManager.createOffScreen(Unknown Source)
at online.common.RepaintManager.paintCanvas(Unknown Source)
at online.common.RepaintManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
at lib.Platform_Codename1.runInEdt(Unknown Source)
at online.common.RepaintManager.repaintCanvas(Unknown Source)
at online.common.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at online.common.exCanvas.paint(Unknown Source)
at bridge.ComponentProxy.paint(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1323)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1297)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1272)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

That's the Android native VM, we don't do anything to it.

If line numbers are missing it is due to Google.

I did notice that the code isn't obfuscated which is probably not a good idea especially in an app as huge as yours.

Comment: I'm not concerned about piracy.  It's a free app, and I prefer to get good debugging information.   Are you claiming that android vm can somehow get line numbers for your library classes but not for mine?  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm not claiming that, it's a fact. Obfuscation increases performance significantly & reduces download size. It's not just for IP protection... A 60% decrease in size is important.

Comment: ok, I"ll accept your point about obfuscation, what about the line numbers?

Comment: That was the "I'm not claiming that's a fact". Download the native code... Look thru it. There is no "magic" there and no custom VM. If Google stripped out the line numbers that's them.

Comment: My understanding of the build process is that you digest the jar file and emit a new android source file which is then compiled.  Somehow this process yields line numbers for codename1.jar but not for my jars, so there must be some difference in the overall build process.

Comment: We submit the jar file to dex. The source that is there is "roughly" the source from the open source project. You can use include source and replace the jars with your code.